# Using AJAX function in added row

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, function, html-table

In my page user can click on button (add question) to add new row 
In each row CLO value will be determine based on Keyword and chapter he provide function `CLO()` will be call after selecting the chapter. I'm trying to call `CLO()` function in each row and set the response in that row.
Is it possible?

```
  <html><head>
    <script>
            function addRow(tableID){
        var table=document.getElementById(tableID);
         var rowCount=table.rows.length;
        var row=table.insertRow(rowCount);
        var colCount=table.rows[1].cells.length;
        var cell1=row.insertCell(0);
        cell1.innerHTML= rowCount+1;
        for(var i=0;i<colCount;i++){
        var newcell=row.insertCell(i+1);
        newcell.innerHTML=table.rows[1].cells[i+1].innerHTML;
        }}
    function CLO() {
    var a=document.getElementById("keyword").value;
    var b=document.getElementById("chapter").value;
        if (a == ""&& b == "") {
            document.getElementById("CLO").innerHTML = "";

            return;
        } else { 
         if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            } else {
                // code for IE6, IE5
                xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                    document.getElementById("CLO").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;

                }
            }

           xmlhttp.open("GET","PLO.php?q1="+escape(a)+"&q2="+escape(b),true);
    xmlhttp.send();
        }
    }

        </script>
        </head><body><form>
        <input type="button" value="Add Question" onclick="addRow('dataTable')"><br> <br>

        <table id="dataTable" >
        <tr><th>Q</th><th>Keyword</th>
    <th>Chapter</th>
    <th>CLO</th> 
    <th> Marks</th></tr>
    <tr><td> 1</td><td> <input type="text" name="keyword" id="keyword" > </td> 
     <td> &nbsp;&nbsp; <select name="chapter" id="chapter" onchange="CLO()"> <option value="" >  </option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>

    </select></td>

    <td id="CLO"> </td>  </td>

    <td> <input type="text" name="Assess_Mark"> </td></tr>

    </table><form></body></html>
```

Comment: @Asma If maybe is this your question that you are unable to call CLO function from new added row ? then atleast give us the new added row's html, what is being created.

Comment: @vinayakj based on addRow() function the new added row will have the same HTML as the original row

Comment: @Asma I highly doubt that , I cant see any onchange event being assigned callback CLO function in addrow function. can you please provide that html after run.

Comment: better you create a jsFiddle at https://jsfiddle.net/ so that it would be more clear

Comment: @vinayakj https://jsfiddle.net/q94yaf6r/2/embedded/result/

Comment: using jsfiddle the addrow button didn't work, but work on my page. I'm really confuse. Maybe I should add new row using another method, what do you recommend me to do@vinayakj

Comment: there is setting on left in jsFiddle change it to no wrap- in head the add row would work.. while I am looking into the code

Comment: ohh you are having ids to keyword and chapter fields same in all added rows, you need to have the dynamic id for each row as html dont allow duplicate ids

Comment: update your addRow function so that new row would have the diff ids for "keyword" and "chapter" and pass the values of these two field in CLO(key, chap) itself;

Comment: @vinayakj I add newcell.id=table.rows[1].cells[i+1].id+rowCount; to addrow function, but I'm not sure about it. what do you think  and could you please help me with the writing the code for passing the values to CLO()

Comment: @Asma the above code would assign ids to td not the keyword and chapter field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Modified html

```
<body><form>
            <input type="button" value="Add Question" onclick="addRow('dataTable')"><br> <br>
        <table id="dataTable" >
        <tr><th>Q</th><th>Keyword</th>
        <th>Chapter</th>
        <th>CLO</th> 
        <th> Marks</th></tr>
        <tr id=0><td> 1</td><td> <input type="text" name="keyword"> </td> 
         <td> &nbsp;&nbsp; <select name="chapter" onchange="CLO(this.parentElement.parentElement.id)"> <option value="" >  </option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>

        </select></td>

        <td id="CLO"> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>  </td>

        <td> <input type="text" name="Assess_Mark"> </td></tr>

        </table><form></body>
```

The modified JS

```
 function addRow(tableID){
            var table=document.getElementById(tableID);
            var rowCount=table.rows.length;
            var row=table.insertRow(rowCount);
            row.id = Number(table.rows[rowCount-1].id)+1;
            var colCount=table.rows[1].cells.length;
            var cell1=row.insertCell(0);
            cell1.innerHTML= rowCount;
            for(var i=1;i<colCount;i++){
            var newcell=row.insertCell(i);
            newcell.innerHTML=table.rows[1].cells[i].innerHTML;
            }
  }
  function CLO(rowID) {
        var a=document.getElementsByName("keyword")[rowID].value;
        var b=document.getElementsByName("chapter")[rowID].value;
            console.log("marks = "+a +" chapter = "+b)
            if (a == ""&& b == "") {
                document.getElementById("CLO").innerHTML = "";

                return;
            } else { 
             if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                } else {
                    // code for IE6, IE5
                    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                }
                xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                        document.getElementById("CLO").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;

                    }
                }

               xmlhttp.open("GET","PLO.php?q1="+escape(a)+"&q2="+escape(b),true);
        xmlhttp.send();
            }
     }
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help I really a appreciate it, I tried the modified code it work in first added row only and display the respond in original row and I tried to make it work but I failed :(

Comment: you were right, but that much error you should capture, that will help you develop more skills in debuging, anyways I corrected the code now.