# Assign dynamic id for textbox and call it in another function

Tags: javascript, dynamic, html-table, textbox, popup

I have table with 4 td and user can add row by clicking button and inside each td I have textbox and one of them I have button which open popup window. When user click on this button the popup window will appear with checkboxes after user checked checkboxes the value of them will appear in textbox of parent page that is in same td of button clicked. My problem is when I added new row the value of checked checkboxes only appear in first textbox not in new row, for that I want to assign dynamic id for each added row and post value of checked checkboxes to it. I'm only using Javascript, PHP and html.
This is my parent.php code:

```html
 <html>
     <head>
     <script>
     function addRow(in_tbl_name)
       {
     var tbody =      document.getElementById(in_tbl_name).getElementsByTagName("TBODY")[0];
    // create row
    var rrowCount = tbody.rows.length;
    var row = document.createElement("TR");
    var td1 = document.createElement("TD");
    var strHtml1 = "<INPUT TYPE=\"text\" SIZE=\"255\" MAXLENGTH=\"255\" class=\"textborder\">";
      td1.innerHTML=strHtml1 ;
         var td2 = document.createElement("TD");
         var strHtml2 = "<INPUT TYPE='text' name='ch' id='ch' class=\"textbordersmall\">" +"<INPUT TYPE='text' SIZE=\"30\" MAXLENGTH=\"255\" id='clo' name='clo' class=\"textbordersmall\">";
      td2.innerHTML=strHtml2;
         var td3 = document.createElement("TD");
      var strHtml3 ="<textarea value='' overflow-Y='auto' width='20' height='10' name='txtName' readonly='readonly'></textarea>"+"<input type='submit' value='PLO'/>";

 td3.innerHTML=strHtml3 ;
 var td4= document.createElement("TD");
    var strHtml4 = "<INPUT TYPE=\"text\" NAME=\"in_name\" SIZE=\"5\" MAXLENGTH=\"255\" class=\"textbordersmall\">";
 td4.innerHTML=strHtml4 ;
    // append data to row
    row.appendChild(td1);
    row.appendChild(td2);
    row.appendChild(td3);
    row.appendChild(td4);
    // append row to table
   tbody.appendChild(row);
      }}
       function deleterow(tableID) {
   var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
 if (rowCount==1){return false;}
 if (rowCount==2&&num==1){num++;}
 else{
 num--;
    table.deleteRow(rowCount -1);
 
     }}
     </script>
     </head>
     <body>
     <form action="pop.php" method="POST" name="login" onsubmit="process(); return false;">
     <TABLE ID="tbl" width="570" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" class="st">
     <TH WIDTH="400">Content</TH><TH WIDTH="57">CLO</TH><TH WIDTH="57">PLO</TH>          <TH WIDTH="56">Week</TH>
     <p align="center">
     <INPUT TYPE="Button" onClick="addRow('tbl')" VALUE="Add Row">&nbsp;&nbsp;
     <INPUT TYPE="Button" onClick="deleterow('tbl')" VALUE="delete Row">     </p>&nbsp;&nbsp;

     </TABLE></form>
     </body>
     </html>
```

And this my pop.php code:

```html
     <html>
     <body>
      <input type="checkbox" name="c[]" id="ddlNames" value="E1">E1
         <br />
      <input type="checkbox" name="c[]" id="ddlNames" value="E2">E2
         <br />
      <input type="checkbox" name="c[]" id="ddlNames" value="E3">E3
         <br />
     <p align="center"><input type="submit" value="Select" onclick="SetName()" /></p>    </form>
      <script type="text/javascript">
         function SetName() {
      var frm = document.forms[0];
         var txt = "";
         var i;
         for (i = 0; i < frm.length; i++) {
        if (frm[i].checked) {
            txt = txt + frm[i].value + " ";
        }
         }
      for (s=0; s<200; s++){
            var txtName = window.opener.document.getElementById('txtName');
            txtName.value = txt;
      }
        window.close();
       }
      </script>
       <body>
       </html>
```

Comment: this is probably an easy answer, but you've posted too much code and haven't described the problem in a way that is easy to interpret :/

Comment: This is my code and i appreciate your help. @wahwahwah

Comment: I have already answered similar question, I ll give you the link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29718750/using-ajax-function-in-added-row?noredirect=1#answer

Comment: possible duplicate of [using AJAX function in added row](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29718750/using-ajax-function-in-added-row)

Comment: thanks for your help but i need another way not AJAX.